# Why does this database script not return any results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, and I can't fix it myself neither of the help of a friend.

Basically the thing I try to do is, call a PHP script with 2 arguments: `username` and `subscriptionid`.

The PHP script should read out the userid by the username from a table called "user". Then, in another table, called `subscriptionlog`, check if the userid is there and if so, see if he has an entry with the `subscriptionid`. If so, print out the "status" variable of that table.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

// checkkey.php?user=ZeD&subid=2 -> Called as GET

$servername     = "localhost";
$username       = "username";
$password       = "password";
$dbname         = "database";

$uname      = $_GET["user"];
$subid      = $_GET["subid"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT status FROM subscriptionlog WHERE subscriptionid = '$subid' AND userid = (SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = '$uname')";
$result = mysqli_query( $sql );

if( $result === false )
    echo( "error with bitch sql" );

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
    echo $row["status"];
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

It just leaves the page blank, there's no echo happening at all.

Comment: did you try this query on mysql client? do you see any output?

Comment: Change the if ($result === 0) to if ($result === false) as mysqli will only return False/True/mysqli_result, never an actual 0. This'll make sure that the query isn't failing, at which point you can test against mysql directly as that's most likely the culprit.

Comment: you have a sql syntax error

Comment: ... you have a SQL injection vulnerability also.

Comment: it works with this code in phpMyAdmin

Comment: "it works with this code in phpMyAdmin". Pantomime voice in reply: _oh no it doesn't!_

Comment: Also: `mysqli_query() expects the first parameter to be bla bla bla`. You want `$con->query()`. Well, `$con->prepare()` actually...

Comment: As per @jeroen's comment, see the parameters you need to supply here: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1):

Try adding at the top of your page :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

so you can see if you have any error.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/zedcheat/public_html/authkey.php on line 25

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/zedcheat/public_html/authkey.php on line 30

Comment: Those are the 2 warnings which appear after using your code

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given, so try this : $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Answer (score 1):

this is probably your issue, you are missing an ending `)` from your sql statement

```
$sql = "SELECT status FROM subscriptionlog WHERE subscriptionid = '$subid' AND userid = (SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = '$uname')";
```

And your query call should look like this, with the `$conn` as the first param

```
mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
```

Comment: well I kinda deleted it by accident when posting here. It's in my script on the server though

Comment: Look at @jeroen's comment.  Your very next line should be `mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to check for NULL rather than 0

```
if ($result === NULL) { echo "My result is null" };
```